# Docker build: Not showing dist folder after ng build

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I'm trying to containerize an angular-9 application.

dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app

# Install & build packages
RUN npm install
# Listing 1
RUN ls -la 
RUN npm run build:docker
# Listing 2
Run ls -la

# Setup nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/  /usr/share/nginx/html/ 

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
```

Package.json

```
script: {
"build:docker": "node --max-old-space-size=10240 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --output-path=dist"
}
```

`#Listing 1(in dokerfile)` shows `node-modules` folder but `Listing 2(in dokerfile)` doesn't.
Also in the end, it throws error

```
COPY failed: stat app/dist/: file does not exist
```

I'm unable to understand why it is not fetching files which were build in docker.

I'm adding the screenshot of logs below.
[image]

Comment: Can you also show the output of `npm run build:docker`?

Comment: it just compiled successfully

Comment: I've added a screenshot of logs in the question.

Comment: Can you add the actual logs, instead of a screen shot?  It would be much easier to read and search for later.

Comment: I noticed one thing, if I do docker build on the windows machine, it works perfectly fine but if I do it on Linux or Mac, it gives the same error. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: I had the same issue but in my case, it was a RAM issue only. Added some swap memory and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What about this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.0-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci
# node_modules installed

COPY . .
RUN npm run build:docker
# dist filled with your build app

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

you should have a `.dockerignore` file in the same directory containing

```
dist
node_modules
```

This should install exactly the versions of package-lock.json via `npm ci`. It doesn't copy dist or node_module directories through the `.dockerignore` and speeds up your build.

If this all doesn't help, please provide the output of `RUN npm run build:docker`.

Comment: Tried everything you said about but nothing helped. I'ne added output logs in the question above.

Comment: When you run build:docker locally, where is dist generated?

Comment: yes, it gets generated. And it's not just about the dist folder, even node-modules is not there.

Comment: node_modules has to be there, because docker:build doesn't fail....
What about using only `ng build --prod` in build:docker and copying from `dist/app`?

Comment: I noticed one thing if I do docker build on the windows machine, it works perfectly fine but if I do it on Linux or Mac, it gives the same error. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: You can maybe try passing `--no-cache` or `--pull`, if it's a problem of docker.

Comment: Already using --no-cache. This is my build command `docker build --no-cache=true --rm=false -t avl_project_ui .`

Comment: any news on this @mohitsharma I have the same issue on linux

Comment: I have the same issue on mac, any news?